# approximate identity of a *-algebra.

Tags: operator-theory

I know that a *-algebra does not always have an approximate unit. Why does a non-degnarate *-algebra which is $\sigma-strongly^*$ closed have an approximate unit?

Comment: What is an approximate unit in a general $*$-algebra? Do you mean a normed $*$-algebra? Banach $*$-algebra?

Comment: Yurii: yes, I mean a Banach *-algebra.

Answer (score 2):

By virtue of Von Neumann bicommutant theorem if $\mathcal{M}$ is a non-degenetare $*$-algebra which is $\sigma$-strongly closed* then $\mathcal{M}= \mathcal{M}^{\prime \prime}$ ($\mathcal{M}$ equals to its second commutant). Therefore, such $\mathcal{M}$ is a von Neumann algebra. (References Takesaki 'Theory of Operator Algebras I' Theorem 3.9 p.74). 
Every von Neumann algebra is a unital C*-algebra (it has even more than approximate identity, it has an identity).

Another result which is relevant to your question is:

Corollary 7.5 p. 28 in Takesaki `Theory of Operator Alegbras I'

Any C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ admits an approximate identity. Moreover, if $\mathcal{A}$ is separable, then it admist an approximate identity consisting of a sequence.

Comment: Deyton: Thanks for your answer. my teacher before showing M be a von Neumann, used an approximate unit for it and with this net show that M has unit. In my opinion, first I must know that M has an approximate unit, but I cannot show it. it is my problem.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{M}$ is $\sigma$-strongly closed* it is also closed in a norm topology, thus $\mathcal{M}$ is a C*-alegbra. Now, as I wrote in my answer any C*-algebra admits an approximate identity (you can find this proof in any book about Operator Algebras). You can show that $\mathcal{M}$ is unital using this fact, but you don't have to. You can also apply Krein-Milman theorem, and the fact that a C*-algebra is unital if and only if there exists an extreme point in its closed unit ball.